# FragmentTransaction adds content to the wrong LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have a search interface (with an android search widget). When I retrieve results, each results is wrapped into a [folding-cell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android). Once the folding-cell is loaded, I fill the cell-title with a simple TextView. Then, I fill the content with a TextView (which works). In addition to the TextView, my cell-content also contains a LinearLayout. I use this layout to add a fragment, using a FragmentTransaction. 
My problem is that each fragment is supposed to fill a different folding-cell, but only they all adds to the first folding-cell (so I guess that FragmentTransaction manager is adding all fragments to the same LinearLayout, the one of the first Folding-Cell).

***Here is a screen of 1st and 2nd folding-cells, unfolded:***
[image: Here is a screen of 1st and 2nd folding-cells, unfolded]

Here is the code for the search results :

```
             try {
                JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject row = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("email", row.getString("email"));
                    args.putString("name", row.getString("nom_organisme"));
                    Fragment newFragment = new FragmentOrganisationFoldingCell();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_organisation_presentation_for_search, newFragment).commit();
                    organisationList.add(newFragment);
                }

                if(jsonarr.length() == 0){
                    errorText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here is the FramgmentOrganisationFoldingCell:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_organisation_folding_cell, container, false);

        final FoldingCell fc = (FoldingCell) view.findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);

        Bundle args = getArguments();

        TextView organisationName = view.findViewById(R.id.search_organisation_default_name);
        organisationName.setText(args.getString("name"));
        TextView t = view.findViewById(R.id.cell_content);
        t.setText(args.getString("name"));

        LinearLayout fragContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cell_content_frag);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragContainer.getId(), new FragmentProfileOrganisation(), "Organisation" + args.getString("name")).commit();

        fc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fc.toggle(false);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Here is fragment_organisation_folding_cell, which is the view I inflate in FragmentOrganisationFoldingCell :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/block">
    <com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/folding_cell"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
        <!-- CONTENT (UNFOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times BIGGER than content layout bellow)-->
        <include layout="@layout/cell_content_layout" />

        <!-- TITLE (FOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times SMALLER than content layout above) -->
        <include layout="@layout/cell_title_layout" />
    </com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the XML code for the cell_content_layout, which contains the LinearLayout I use to add my fragments. (So I beleive that this is the file that creates the trouble).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/cell_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cell_content_frag">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the fragment_organisation_search XML file :

```
...
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/block"
            android:id="@+id/container_organisation_presentation_for_search"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

        </LinearLayout>
...
```

Do anyone have any trouble adding fragments into Folding-cells too? If anyone have any idea I would be really thankful !

Answer (score 0):

The following command in your code that is parsing search results will add `newFragment` to a view with ID `R.id.container_organisation_presentation_for_search`. That ID is in your XML for the actual fragment.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_organisation_presentation_for_search, newFragment).commit();
```

I think instead what you want may be:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.cell_content_frag, newFragment).commit();
```

Comment: First, thanks for trying to help me. This can't work, as `cell_content_frag` is the XML file inflated in `newFragment`. It is not in the calling parent which parses search results. I can't add it to the layout that the parent uses because the `cell_content_frag` must be part of the folding cell, and I can't just add folding-cells to parent's layout as I want to create them dynamically. (That's why I use `FragmentTransaction`). What I want to do is add a wrapper (folding-cell) for each result, and I need it to wrap a fragment. It is supposed to wrap a `cell_content_frag`.